# Modify file using Files.lines

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'd like to read in a file and replace some text with new text.  It would be simple using asm and int 21h but I want to use the new java 8 streams.

```
    Files.write(outf.toPath(), 
        (Iterable<String>)Files.lines(inf)::iterator,
        CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

Somewhere in there I'd like a `lines.replace("/*replace me*/","new Code()\n");`.  The new lines are because I want to test inserting a block of code somewhere.

Here's a play example, that doesn't work how I want it to, but compiles.  I just need a way to intercept the lines from the iterator, and replace certain phrases with code blocks.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ss = new String[]{"hi","pls","help","me"};
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(ss);

        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("tmp.txt"),
                    (Iterable<String>)stream::iterator,
                    CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {}

//// I'd like to hook this next part into Files.write part./////
        //reset stream
        stream = Arrays.stream(ss);
        Iterable<String> it = stream::iterator;
        //I'd like to replace some text before writing to the file
        for (String s : it){
            System.out.println(s.replace("me", "my\nreal\nname"));
        }
    }

}
```

edit: I've gotten this far and it works.  I was trying with filter and maybe it isn't really necessary.

```
        Files.write(Paths.get("tmp.txt"),
                 (Iterable<String>)(stream.map((s) -> {
                    return s.replace("me", "my\nreal\nname");
                }))::iterator,
                CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want to read some lines of text from a file, replace those lines with some other text (maybe through regex), and writes those lines back to the file? Is that right?

Comment: Exactly.  Maybe I'll explain better in the question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `Files.write(..., Iterable, ...)` method seems tempting here, but converting the Stream to an Iterable makes this cumbersome. It also "pulls" from the Iterable, which is a bit odd. It would make more sense if the file-writing method could be used as the stream's terminal operation, within something like `forEach`.

Unfortunately, most things that write throw `IOException`, which isn't permitted by the `Consumer` functional interface that `forEach` expects. But PrintWriter is different. At least, its writing methods don't throw checked exceptions, although opening one can still throw `IOException`. Here's how it could be used.

```
Stream<String> stream = ... ;
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8")) {
    stream.map(s -> s.replaceAll("foo", "bar"))
          .forEachOrdered(pw::println);
}
```

Note the use of `forEachOrdered`, which prints the output lines in the same order in which they were read, which is presumably what you want!

If you're reading lines from an input file, modifying them, and then writing them to an output file, it would be reasonable to put both files within the same try-with-resources statement:

```
try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"));
     PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8"))
{
    input.map(s -> s.replaceAll("foo", "bar"))
         .forEachOrdered(output::println);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much cleaner than mine, and yes I'm reading an input file.